# Scanner breaking after entering 2 words

Tags: java

I have a problem with the "model" scanner. My program requires me to enter vehicles from a predetermined chart. Some of the vehicles are two words example : "Grand Caravan". I understand why its giving me other then being two words its because the next scanner is a double which doesn't allow characters so it errors out. I just want to include the white space and 2nd word in a single scanner if possible, or is there another way of doing this?

```
String make, model;
    double cityMPG, hwyMPG;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter your cars make"); // asking for cars make
        make  = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Enter your cars model"); // asking for cars model
        model = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Enter your gas tank size"); // asking for gas tank size
        tanksize = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter your city MPG"); // asking for City MPG1
        cityMPG = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter your highway MPG"); // asking for Highway MPG
        hwyMPG = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `keyboard.nextLine()` instead of `keyboard.next()`.

Comment: Thanks I was able to do it with a keyboard.next() and a keyboard.nextLine() after it to catch any text the first missed.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in [Scanner.nextLine() JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) will explain what you want.

For the future, when you are faced with similar issues, look into the JavaDocs for the object you're using. Many times, just browsing through the methods will find you one that does what you need.